# for unetbootin, on Ubuntu 19.04, PPA: gezakovacs does work

Tags: system-installation

When I attempt to install unetbootin on my Ubuntu 19.04 system, I get: "E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file."  message ---- what PPA can I use to get unetbootin to work properly?

Comment: Which steps did you follow to add the PPA?

Comment: That PPA doesn't support 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for those on Ubuntu 19.04 who cannot install the unetbootin app, I suggest that they do a Google on "unetbootin-linux64-661.bin' and download this progam to their bin area and execute it and it works well on 19.04.

Comment: Also, for those on Ubuntu 19.04 who cannot install the unetbootin app, I suggest that they do a Google on "unetbootin-linux64-661.bin' and download this progam to their bin area and execute it and it works well on 19.04.